# Template template variadic parameter specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I was wondering if there was a way to specialize a template in the following way:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Typelist { };

template<template<typename> typename... TTs>
class Typelist<TTs<typename>> { };   //I don't know if that is the right syntax, at least the compiler doesn't complain
```

I want it to work as a list of templated types as well as a list of non-templated types:

```
template<typename T>
class AT {};

template<typename T>
class BT {};

template<typename T>
class CT {};

int main() {

    using tl1 = Typelist<int, float, double>;   //works fine
    using tl2 = Typelist<AT, BT, CT>;   //gives an error

}
```

#### Edit:

If I declare the secont `Typelist` as a seperate type it works...

```
template<template<typename> typename... TTs>
class Typelist2 { };

//...
using tl2 = Typelist2<AT, BT, CT>;   //compiler doesn't complain and it works fine
```

I was wondering though if it was possible to use only `Typelist` for both cases so that `Typelist2` doesn't have to be a seperate type.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `AT`, `BT`, `CT` are templates of a class, and you are not specifying templated type. How should the compiler know the underlying type of those templates, if it isn't stated in any way? Note: Templates are compile-time construct.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I edited my question accordingly...

Comment: You can't have the same template take a type as an argument sometimes, and a template other times, for the same parameter. Each template parameter is either a type parameter, a non-type parameter, or a template parameter; specialization cannot change that.

Comment: I don't think the syntax `class Typelist<TTs<typename>>` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering though if it was possible to use only Typelist for both cases so that Typelist2 doesn't have to be a seperate type.

I don't think so.

Because `TypeList` is defined as `template<typename... Ts>` or `template<template<typename> typename... TTs>`; both definition can't work togheter.

The best I can imagine to help you is define a `TypeList` base version for simple types

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct TypeList
 {
   // here you can use Ts...
 };
```

and a specialization for containers (with only a type in it) as follows

```
template <template <typename> class ... Tts, typename ... Ts>
struct TypeList<Tts<Ts>...>
 {
   // here you can use Ts... and Tts...
 };
```

where you can use `Ts` and `Tts`.

But isn't a great solution because you can't define a containers `TypeList` simply as

```
TypeList<AT, BT, CT> tcl;
```

but you have to add contained dummy (?) types as follows

```
TypeList<AT<int>, BT<float>, CT<double>> tl2;
```

Another problem is you can't mix they, so

```
TypeList<AT<int>, BT<float>, double> tl;
```

call the base version (no containers) of `TypeList`.

Comment: The last problem is no problem for me because I intend to use either templated types or non-templated types but not both